# Efficient way to count unique pairs in int array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, int

This is my first post, hope it complies with posting guidelines of the site.
First of all a generic thanks to all the community: reading you from some months and learned a lot :o)

Premise: I'm a first years student of IT.

Here's the question: I'm looking for an efficient way to count the number of unique pairs (numbers that appear exactly twice) in a given positive int array (that's all I know), e.g. if:

```
int[] arr = {1,4,7,1,5,7,4,1,5};
```

the number of unique pairs in arr is 3 (4,5,7).

I have some difficulties in... evaluating the efficiency of my proposals let's say.

Here's the first code I did:

```
int numCouples( int[] v ) {
int res = 0;
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < v.length; i++){
    count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < v.length; j++){
        if (i != j && v[i] == v[j]){
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == 1){
        res++;
    }
}
return res/2;
}
```

This shoudn't be good cause it checks the whole given array as many times as the number of elements in the given array... correct me if I'm wrong.

This is my second code:

```
int numCouples( int[] v) {
int n = 0;
int res = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
    if (v[i] > n){
        n = v[i];
    }
}
int[] a = new int [n];
for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
    a[v[i]-1]++;
}
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    if (a[i] == 2){
        res++;
    }
}
return res;
}
```

I guess this should be better than the first one since it checks only 2 times the given array and 1 time the n array, when n is the max value of the given array. May be not so good if n is quite big I guess...

Well, 2 questions:

1. am I understanding good how to "measure" the efficiency of the code?
2. there's a better way to count the number of unique pairs in a given array?

EDIT:
Damn I've just posted and I'm already swamped by answers! Thanks! I'll study each one with care, for the time being I say I don't get those involving HashMap: out of my knowledge yet (hence thanks again for the insight:o) )

Comment: What do you mean by Unique pair?

Comment: How is `5` amongst unique pair in your example array?

Comment: what do you mean with unique pairs? i don't understand why the number of "unique pairs" is not 4.

Comment: I think, with unique pairs he means numbers that appear exactly twice.

Comment: Sorry I corrected the given example array. With 'unique pairs' I mean... just a couple. If there are more than 2 occurrences of a value, it doesn't count as a 'unique pair' (hope to clarified it, english isn't my nativa language sorry)

jlordo got it! I've edited my post :o)

Comment: You can implement your own sort (insertion sort) and keep track of duplicates- and therefore unique pairs- as you go

Comment: why does everone want to sort the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's another answer to your's 2 questions:

```
am I understanding good how to "measure" the efficiency of the code?
```

There are various ways to measure efficiency of the code. First of all, people distinguish between *memory efficiency* and *time efficiency*. The usual way to count all these values is to know, how efficient are the building blocks of your algorithm. Have a look at the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithmic_efficiency).

For instance, sorting using quicksort would need `n*log(n)` operations. Iterating through the array would need just `n` operations, where `n` is number of elements in the input.

```
there's a better way to count the number of unique pairs in a given array?
```

Here's another solution for you. The complixity of this one would be: `O(n*log(n)+n)`, where `O(...)` is [Big O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Ctest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int[] { 1, 4, 7, 1, 7, 4, 1, 5, 5, 8 };
    System.out.println("RES: " + uniquePairs(a));
  }

  public static int uniquePairs(int[] a) {
    Arrays.sort(a);
    // now we have: [1, 1, 1, 4, 4, 5, 5, 7, 7]

    int res = 0;
    int len = a.length;
    int i = 0;

    while (i < len) {
      // take first number
      int num = a[i];
      int c = 1;
      i++;

      // count all duplicates
      while(i < len && a[i] == num) {
        c++;
        i++;
      }
      System.out.println("Number: " + num + "\tCount: "+c);
      // if we spotted number just 2 times, increment result
      if (c == 2) {
        res++;
      }
    }

    return res;
  }
}
```

Comment: Accepted this answer cause it's the only one that tries to answer to both questions... ;) and algorithm is smart too (althougth I sligthy prefer Mikhail Vladimirov implementation, but it's about the same)

Comment: Thanks :) Our algorithms are indeed almost the same, he compares indices while I'm summing up the occurrences.

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = { 1, 4, 7, 1, 5, 7, 4, 1, 5 };

    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        Integer count = map.get(arr[i]);
        if (count == null)
            map.put(arr[i], 1);
        else
            map.put(arr[i], count + 1);
    }

    int uniqueCount = 0;

    for (Integer i : map.values())
        if (i == 2)
            uniqueCount++;

    System.out.println(uniqueCount);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int [] a = new int [] {1, 4, 7, 1, 7, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
Arrays.sort (a);

int res = 0;
for (int l = a.length, i = 0; i < l - 1; i++)
{
    int v = a [i];
    int j = i + 1;
    while (j < l && a [j] == v) j += 1;
    if (j == i + 2) res += 1;
    i = j - 1;
}

return res;
```

Comment: Smart, but won't work for `int [] a = new int [] {1, 4, 7, 1, 7, 4, 1, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1};`

Comment: This isn't especially efficient, though, having to sort the list then loop through it and compare everything.  Granted the OP probably won't care (and if not, then +1 to this), otherwise combine the sort with the count to reduce the order of the operation (e.g. insertion sort)

Comment: @BobFlannigon Any kind of sort will be more time-complex than the hashtable-based approaches. Insertion sort is an even worse choice than quick sort, regardless of the reuse you mention.

Comment: @jlordo It was not clear what is `unique pair`.  Depending on meaning of "unique pair" array `{1, 1, 1, 1}` may contain 1, 2 or 6 "unique pairs".  My example could be easily modified to implement either variant, I just chose meaning that was simpler to implement.

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov: OP clearead up what he means. He means exactly twice in the array. So in your `{1, 1, 1, 1}` example the answer would be 0.

Comment: This is working and is indeed smart. However, as far as I understood, HashMap approach should be more efficient... but have to study still. Thumbs up for the alghorithm!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arr = {1,4,7,1,7,4,1,5};
    Map<Integer, Integer> counts = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    int count = 0;

    for(Integer num:arr){
        Integer entry = counts.get(num);

        if(entry == null){
            counts.put(num, 1);
        }else if(counts.get(num) == 1){
            count++;
            counts.put(num, counts.get(num) + 1);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);

}
```

Comment: Your code may break for test case `[5, 1, 4, 7, 1, 7, 4, 1, 5]`. It should print `2` whereas your code is printing `4`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use HashMap for easy grouping. here is my code.

```
int[] arr = {1,1,1,1,1,1,4,7,1,7,4,1,5};
    HashMap<Integer,Integer> asd = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        if(asd.get(arr[i]) == null)
        {
            asd.put(arr[i], 1);
        }
        else
        {
            asd.put(arr[i], asd.get(arr[i])+1);
        }
    }

    //print out
    for(int key:asd.keySet())
    {
        //get pair
        int temp = asd.get(key)/2;
        System.out.println(key+" have : "+temp+" pair");
    }
```

added for checking the unique pair, you can delete the print out one

```
//unique pair
    for(int key:asd.keySet())
    {
        if(asd.get(key) == 2)
        {
            System.out.println(key+" are a unique pair");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

after some time another solution, which should work great.

```
public getCouplesCount(int [] arr) {
    int i = 0, i2;
    int len = arr.length;
    int num = 0;
    int curr;
    int lastchecked = -1;

    while (i < len-1) {
        curr = arr[i];
        i2 = i + 1;
        while (i2 < len) {
            if (curr == arr[i2] && arr[i2] != lastchecked) {
                num++; // add 1 to number of pairs
                lastchecked = curr; 
                i2++; // iterate to next
            } else if (arr[i2] == lastchecked) {
                // more than twice - swap last and update counter
                if (curr == lastchecked) {
                    num--;
                }
                // swap with last
                arr[i2] = arr[len-1];
                len--;
            } else {
                i2++;
            }
        i++;
    }

return num;
}
```

i am not shure if it works, but it is more effective than sorting the array first, or using hashmaps....

Answer (score 0):

```
var sampleArray = ['A','B','C','D','e','f','g'];
 var count = 0;
 for(var i=0; i<=sampleArray.length; i++) {
    for(var j=i+1; j<sampleArray.length; j++) {
        count++;
        console.log(sampleArray[i] , sampleArray[j]);
    }
 }
 console.log(count);
```

This is the simple way I tried.

Answer (score 0):

A Java8 parallel streamy version which uses a ConcurrentHashMap

```
int[] arr = {1,4,7,1,5,7,4,1,5};
Map<Integer,Long> map=Arrays.stream(arr).parallel().boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
        ConcurrentHashMap::new,Collectors.counting()));
map.values().removeIf(v->v!=2);
System.out.println(map.keySet().size());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;
 int main() 
 {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int arr[9] = {1,4,7,1,5,7,4,1,5};    // given array
    int length=9;                        // this should be given
    int count=0;
    map<int,int> m;
    for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
        m[arr[i]]++;
    cout<<"List of unique pairs : ";
    for(auto it=m.begin();it!=m.end();it++)
        if(it->second==2)
        {
            count++;
            cout<<it->first<<" ";
        }
    cout<<"\nCount of unique pairs(appears exactly twice) : "<<count;
    return 0;
 }

 OUTPUT :
 List of unique pairs : 4 5 7 
 Count of unique pairs(appears exactly twice) : 3

 Time Complexity : O(N) where N is the number of elements in array
 Space Complexity : O(N) total no. of unique elements in array always <=N
```

Comment: Please add some description so that feature readers can understand